# Safari only displays PHP code - Firefox asks which app to display same

Tags: php, firefox, safari

Aloha everyone,

I have a class assignment in which I am tasked to build a MySql database, then use PHP to retrieve the contents of the table in the database.  When I attempt to open this in Safari, it only outputs the HTML/PHP code.  Firefox, on the other hand, pops up a window asking me to select an application to work with the code.  Here is the code itself.  Can anyone see where my error lies and/or point me in the right direction to get this actually interpreted and display correctly?  Any and all assistance will be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>iBud's Sizzling Tracks!</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
  $con = mysql_connct("localhost","*****","**************");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

  mysql_select_db("music", $con);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs");

  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>Song Number</th>
  <th>Song Title</th>
  <th>Artist</th>
  <th>Rating</th>
  </tr>";

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['songNumber'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['songTitle'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['artistName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['rating'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
  echo "</table>";

  mysql_close($con);
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are accessing the site via a local running webserver (like `http://localhost/yoursite/index.php`)? Or are you accessing the file directly via `file:///path/to/file.php`?

Comment: I installed XAMPP from the xampp-macosx-1.7.3.dmg file, but I'll check both the Apache and PHP settings to see if I can find anything.  Thanks for your response, Paul :D

Comment: mAu, I was using the second option.  I my case, the URL I tried was: file:///Users/iBud/IS6050c.php

Comment: @iBud You need to access the file through your web-server, not the local file system.

Comment: mAu, I dropped in the htdocs folder for XAMPP and found one error :(  I missed an 'e' in the mysql_connect statement.  I'll correct that and see if it all works.

Comment: OK, now I'm getting a different error.  I can't seem to authenticate with either 'root' or 'admin' even though I put the right passwords in the php code section for the connection.  Thanks for the responses - you were all correct, and I'll get started on figuring out the authentication issue.

Comment: Here's my question now.  I can access the database through the terminal just fine with passwords, but I can't access the database via the php file, with the same password for the same user account.  Why?

Comment: Try connecting to 127.0.0.1 and not `localhost`. Sometimes this helps. And check the port, the database is running on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the file name actually .php? And are you running PHP on Apache? Are you viewing the page via the webserver (e.g. http://localhost/index.php).

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a PHP interpreted installed on your webserver (or your webserver isn't parsing the PHP file because it isn't named with a `.php` extension). You should *never* be seeing the PHP code from a webbrowser.

I suggest you get a webserver installed and setup PHP. To make this easier, get [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html); it contains PHP, MySQL, Apache and a simple control panel.

Comment: I installed XAMPP already.  My issue was in accessing the file via the local file system, vice via the web server.

Answer (score 3):

Your server is not configured to parse .php with the php interpreter. What server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine. It's probably a server configuration issue OR your file is not saved as a .php file

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver isn't configured to interpret .php files as - well - PHP files. On Windows, consider installing WAMP; on Mac, MAMP. They make this whole process far easier...

Consider laying out your track data in a table - it will look neater than just strings...